# localStorage.getItem returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently making an incremental game using Javascript & HTML. The game features a save system via localStorage but in my function to load all of the game data localStorage returns NaN. could somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Here's the loadData(); function:

```
function loadData() {
    doco = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dogco'));
    updateDC();
    clipo = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('u1'));
    cpwr.innerHTML = `Clickpower: ${clipo}`
    clipes = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('u2'))
    cps.innerHTML = `Clicks Per Second: ${clipes}`;
    cpsok = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('cps'));
    if(cpsok = 1){
        cpsGo();
    }
};
```

Comment: have you saved them to localstorage?

Comment: What is in the `localStorage`? Apparently not a number - `NaN`.

Comment: It's not the `localStorage.getItem()` function that's returning that error, it's the `parseInt()` function. NaN stands for Not a Number. I would start by looking at what is actually in the storage and go from there.

Comment: Side note: Your `if()` is invalid using only a single `=` that is used for variable assignment. Equality check requires multiple `=`

Comment: What are you writing to `localStorage`? Maybe it's not a number. `parseInt` will even return `NaN` if the argument is undefined (the key doesn't exist). Open Developer Tools (on Chrome or Firefox) and check what `localStorage` is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've declared the localStorage prior, but it needs to exist before you can call it.

```
    localStorage.setItem("yourStorage", "value"); // setItem() creates localStorage
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("yourStorage")) //getItem() returns given key's value.


    expected output:
    >"value"
```